# Discere and Studere

Tags: vocabulary

When "discere" can be synonymous with "studere"?

I read an old book saying that:
 "discere" and "studere" aren't usually synonymous, but they can be in some particular contexts.

I'd like to know in which contexts it could be the case.
Could you give some examples (at least 2, to be sure it can be in several contexts).

Comment: The basic expectation is that you'll put in some effort of your own to find an answer for yourself before you post a question, and that you'll share the results of that effort. Did you try looking up both words for yourself in a good Latin dictionary (e.g., for Latin-to-English lookup, the online Lewis & Short dictionary) and examining the examples provided there? What did you find? To improve the quality of the question, you should also provide the author and title of the book that you refer to, and, if you haven't quoted the exact passage, you should do that (even if it isn't in English).

Comment: I looked in 5 or 6 online dictionaries, made intensive google books search to find the "old book".  Discere and Studere are never considered as synonymous in any of those online dictionaries, except this book. We can guess, from their meaning in English, that their meaning could overlap sometimes, it's the reason why I did this search;